# How does Javascript handle exported module-level variables?

Tags: javascript

In a Javascript app, I have a service that is defined as a module, e.g. in `services/MyService.js`.

Say that the service looks like so:

```
let lastUpdated;

function update() {
  lastUpdated = new Date();
}

lastUpdated = new Date();

export default {
  update,
  lastUpdated
}
```

Another file, `index.js`, imports this service:

```
import MyService from "./services";

console.log(MyService.lastUpdated);
setTimeout(() => {
  MyService.update();
  console.log(MyService.lastUpdated);
}, 1000)
```

I would think that `MyService.lastUpdated` would change upon calling `MyService.update()`, but it doesn't. When the variable is imported, is it a pointer to the initial `Date` object? If so, how can I update it so that the "live" variable is accessible elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export default { update, lastUpdated }` exports an *object* with properties `update` and `lastUpdated`. For the problem you're asking about, the object's `lastUpdated` property doesn't get changed for the same reason that `lastUpdated` in the following code doesn't get changed:

```js
let lastUpdated;
function update() {
  lastUpdated = new Date();
}
lastUpdated = new Date();
const MyService = {
  update,
  lastUpdated
};

console.log(MyService.lastUpdated);
setTimeout(() => {
  MyService.update();
  console.log(MyService.lastUpdated);
}, 1000)
```

You're reassigning the *variable* named `lastUpdated`, but you're never mutating the *object* that has been exported, so you don't see a change when you check the object in the other module after calling `update`.

You might export an object that you mutate instead:

```
// MyService.js
function update() {
  console.log("upd");
  obj.lastUpdated = new Date();
}
const obj = {
  update,
  lastUpdated: new Date()
};

export default obj;
```

Another option, though probably not recommended, would be to use named exports instead of the default export of an object. Reassigning a named export in one module *will* result in changes where that export is imported elsewhere:

```
// MyService.js
let lastUpdated;
function update() {
  console.log("upd");
  lastUpdated = new Date();
}
lastUpdated = new Date();
export { update, lastUpdated };

// index.js
import { update, lastUpdated } from "./MyService";
console.log(lastUpdated);
setTimeout(() => {
  update();
  console.log(lastUpdated);
}, 1500);
```

(Reassigning named exports generally makes code more difficult to understand, though, and linters sometimes prohibit it)

Answer (score 0):

The variable cannot be updated live in that sense. What you want is to declare a class with a getter and setter for the `lastUpdated` variable, if you're using ES6:

```
export default class MyService {
    // Member
    constructor() {
        this.lastUpdated = new Date();
    }

    // Method
    update() {
        this.lastUpdated = new Date();
    }
}
```

Then, you can create a new instance of the class `MyService` using `new MyService()`, and then access the `lastUpdated` variable as such:

```
import MyService from "./services";

const myService = new MyService();

// Get current timestamp
console.log(myService.lastUpdated);

window.setTimeout(() => {
    // Update timestamp
    myService.update();

    // Get updated timestamp
    console.log(myService.lastUpdated);
}, 1000);
```